# Package Upgrade Failure dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: apt, dpkg

so Upon upgrading to Ubuntu 14.10 Utopic Unicorn It ran into errors as it tried installing new things and one was Noobslab "Run As Administrator" it failed to upgrade and now im stuck with this when installing it

```
(synaptic:5727): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_child_watch_add_full: assertion 'pid > 0' failed
(Reading database ... 319717 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../open-as-administrator_3.2~utopic~NoobsLab.com_all.deb ...
rm: cannot remove ‘/root/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/Open_as_Administrator’: No such file or directory
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
rm: cannot remove ‘/root/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/Open_as_Administrator’: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/open-as-administrator_3.2~utopic~NoobsLab.com_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
mv: cannot stat ‘/usr/share/bin/Open_as_Administrator’: No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access ‘/root/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/’: No such file or directory

 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 |N o o b s L a B . c o m|
 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+


keep visit on www.NoobsLab.com

Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/open-as-administrator_3.2~utopic~NoobsLab.com_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
```

Comment: Packages are not supposed to (as a matter of packaging policy) touch anything in `/root` or home directories of users.  This package violates policy and ***should not be used***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package is broken.

Your quick'n'dirty hack will be to

```
sudo mkdir -p /root/.local/share/nautilus/scripts
sudo touch /root/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/Open_as_Administrator
```

But as the packages modifies `/root/.local/` I'd say it is in very low quality and would not recommend using it...

Comment: Thank you this allowed me to finally uninstall the script ^^